Can WoS track citations from indexed to non-indexed publications?
I recently registered to Clarivate Web of Science, and synced my Orcid profile with WoS. It detected 11 publications, but it says "Showing 11 publications not indexed in Web of Science". So all metrics, HI-index, and citations are displayed as zero. But I have one publication which got more than 400 citations, based on Google Scholar. Almost half of these citations come from documents in journals that are indexed in WoS. How can I ensure that these citations are credited to me in WoS?
Google Scholar
Orcid
